# how to send https server response to browser using proxy server

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

I am trying to develop proxy server using java.
I follow the steps:

- Browser send request to proxyserver
- Proxy server read the targeted url and communicate with target server.
- Proxy Server read response from targeted server and send back to browser.

The below code  works for http request from browser but not work for https request. When browser hit https url, proxy get response from targeted server but unable to send back to browser. It gives

```
Encountered exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class ProxyThread extends Thread {

private Socket socket = null;
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;
List<RequestProperty> properties;
DataOutputStream out;
BufferedReader in;
String urlToCall;

public ProxyThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ProxyThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        properties = new ArrayList<>();
        String inputLine;

        int cnt = 0;
        String method = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputLine.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(inputLine);

            //parse the first line of the request to find the url
            if (cnt == 0) {
                String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
                method = tokens[0];
                urlToCall = tokens[1];
                System.out.println("Request for : " + urlToCall);

            }
            if (cnt > 0) {
                String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
                String key = tokens[0].replace(":", "");
                String value = "";
                for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    value = value + tokens[i];

                }
                properties.add(new RequestProperty(key, value));
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        //end get request from client

        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("connect")) {
            serveConnect();
        } else {

            serveGet();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void serveGet() {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    try {

        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Request read from clien :::::::\n\n\n\n");

        BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {

            //begin send request to server, get response from server
            URL url = new URL(urlToCall);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            for (RequestProperty property : properties) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());

            }
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // doing HTTP posts
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Get the response
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(
                        "********* IO EXCEPTION **********: " + ioe);
            }
            //end send request to server, get response from server
            System.out.println("RESPOSE TO CLIENT ::::::::::");
            //begin send response to client
            byte by[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int index = is.read(by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            while (index != -1) {
                System.out.println(new String(by));
                out.write(by, 0, index);
                index = is.read(by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            }
            out.flush();

            //end send response to client
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //can redirect this to error log
            System.err.println("Encountered exception: " + e);
            out.writeBytes("");
        }

        //close out all resources
        if (rd != null) {
            rd.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void serveConnect() {
    System.out.println("Connect method called.   ");


    URLConnection conn;
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",
                "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        String url = "https://" + urlToCall;

        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        URL url2 = new URL(url);
        URLConnection con = url2.openConnection();


        for (RequestProperty property : properties) {
            if (!property.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECT")) {
                con.setRequestProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
            }

        }
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            out.write(line.getBytes());
            out.flush();

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Encountered exception: " + e);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: serveGet() method use to handle http request and serveConnect to handle https i.e. "connect" method.

Comment: Use the same BufferedReader for the life of the socket, otherwise you will lose data.